# CakePHP / PHP: remove <th> if there are empty phone values in the array for the current record

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach

My output is working perfect with one exception: some of the people do not have a phone number, and I do not want to include that header (Phone) if there is no phone number available. I have this resolved for the  output. I tried wrapping a foreach around Phone, but of course that repeated the  for each person record group.

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Phone</th> <!-- This <th> should not display if all phone numbers are empty. -->
</tr>
<?php foreach ($persons as $person) : ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php $person['name']; ?></td>
 <td><?php $person['email']; ?></td>
<?php if($person['phone'] != '') { ?> // removes column box if there is no phone number.
 <td><?php $person['phone']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: For clarification, you do not want to include the table header if there is *no phone number available for any user*, i.e. if the whole column would be empty?

Comment: Correct. I am not showing the rest of the application. But I have a list of companies, the people are in companies, so when a company is selected, the people list is displayed for the company. And if there are no records with a phone number, then the Phone <th> should not display, but if there is one phone number (for any person in the company), the header should display. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: For example, if there are no phone numbers for any person, the <th> and <td> section for Phone should not display. I have the <td> section resolved, but the <th> is the problem now. If there is even one phone number, then the <th> should display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  $countEle = count($persons);
  $count = 0;
  foreach($persons as $person) {
    if(empty($person['phone'])) {
        $count++;
    }
  }
  //then you could check as
?>
<?php if($count < $countEle) { ?>
<th>Phone</th>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the array in advance, checking if there's *any* person with a phone number, then use that in a condition. Here's a one-liner for PHP 5.3+:

```
<?php $hasPhone = array_reduce($persons, function ($hasPhone, $person) { return $hasPhone || $person['phone']; }, false); ?>

<table>
<tr>
  ...
  <?php if ($hasPhone) : ?>
    <th>Phone</th>
  <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($persons as $person) : ?>
  ..
  <?php if ($person['phone']) : ?>
    <td><?php $person['phone']; ?></td>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```